# Sublime Text 2 - Autocomplete questions

Tags: macos, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I'm loving Sublime text but there are a few things I'd like to configure on the auto-complete:

**HTML: Auto-completion of attributes within tags**
When adding a class attribute to a div I have to do control+space to get the auto-complete list, is there a way of bringing that up automatically when adding attributes to tags?

**HTML: Adding equals and quotes**
When auto-completing the class attribute I then have to type the equals and quotes, can they be added automatically?

**CSS: Auto-completion of property values**
When I autocomplete a property, e.g. position I then have to add a space and press control+space or start typing to get the values autocomplete list. Is there a way of showing this list straight after the property autocomplete?

I've tried searching for an existing solution but can't find one, so I'm hoping there are some config files that I can amend! Any help pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Darren

Answer (score 1):

Try <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> -> set syntax HTML in order to get auto-completion on html tags

also install: http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control (streamlines package installation process)

and emmet: https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime (makes writing html/css x times faster)

for more information on configuring sublime text you could check:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/sublime-text-2-tips-and-tricks/
and
http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/perfect-workflow-in-sublime-text-free-course/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have [Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control) installed, do that first. Next find the [Tag package](https://github.com/SublimeText/Tag) through Package Control via ST2 and install it. I believe that's the one you're looking for, otherwise [Emmet (Zen Coding)](https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime) could be the one I'm thinking of. Either way, make sure your document syntax is set to HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Definitively for autocompletion install first [Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control) and them Emmet from the Palette Command, just search "emmet" and Enter.